# Swift 3 Upload Image Issue (format)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have to upload image to backend (PHP) and I have to send it with parameter name : "picture"

```
func uploadImage(token: String, userID: Int, imgStr: String,
                 successBlock: @escaping (JSON, Int) -> (),
                 failureBlock: @escaping (String) -> ())
{
    let params: [String: Any] = [
        "picture" : imgStr
    ]        

    Alamofire.request(  "\(API_URL)" + "users/\(userID)",
        method: .put,
        parameters: params,
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: Headers().withToken(token: token)).responseJSON
        { response in

            print(response)
            print(response.result)
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)

            response.result.error != nil
                ? (failureBlock(response.result.error!.localizedDescription))
                : (successBlock(JSON(response.result.value),
                                (response.response?.statusCode)!))
    }
}
```

However I received this message

```
JSON: {
  "picture" : [
    "The picture must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png."
  ]
}
```

There are way to convert UIImage to String with png/jpeg format ?

Many thanks!

Comment: On the server side are they expecting image as base64 string format or file  format ?

Comment: @Rajat they are expecting file format (form-data?)

Comment: but you are sending image as string

Comment: @Rajat I don't know how to send it as "file" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can send image to server with file format

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [String:String]
let URL = try! URLRequest(url: yourURL, method: .put, headers: headers)

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    if let _image = UIImage(named:"") {
        if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "signImg", fileName: "picture.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }
    }
    }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            // hide progressbas here
            print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")
        }
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with Headers?

Comment: I got this msg : Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_to:method:headers:)'

Comment: I just had to replace signImg with picture to match with the parameter's name

Comment: yes you need to update this code as per your requirement

Comment: @Rajat ..can u please tell me, how to upload GIF using Alamofire upload image

Comment: @UmaMadhavi you need to convert your GIF to Data then use the above method to send that data to server, you need to change `mimeType` in the above method

Comment: @Rajat .. let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) in this place how can i convert to image data ..